# understanding nodejs `readline` behavior

Tags: node.js, readline

I am trying out the built-in `readline` module in nodejs and can't understand what is going on in this simple program

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

let count = 0;
let max = 10;

const lineReader = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('verybigfile.txt')
});

lineReader.on('line', function(line) {
    count++;
    if (count > max) {
        lineReader.close();;
    }

    console.log(count);
});
```

The above code prints out 1 .. 138 and then stops. In fact, it counts to 138 for any value of `max` until 137. for `max` from 138 to 275, it prints out 1 .. 276. For 276 to 415, it prints 1 .. 416, and so on. Needless to say, I expect it to print till `max` and then stop because of `rl.close()`

What is going on here?

Comment: Without looking at the code, my guess is "buffering".  If `readline` reads a big chunk of data from the file and then loops over that chunk emitting a `line` event each time it encounters an end-of-line marker, it won't notice that you've called `close()` until it exhausts that chunk and goes back to the file to get the next chunk.  How many *characters* does your linecounter function see before it stops getting called?  What happens if your text file contains only single-character lines?

Comment: ok, I guess as much (buffering) so you confirm it. This also makes `readline` very unsuitable for what I want to do, that is, read lines one by one, do something to them, but have control over what is read. I came to nodejs from the world of Perl, and while I am happy with nodejs, it is amazing to me that such a basic task with nodejs seems to be like pulling teeth. Just search for "node read file line by line" to see the amazing smorgasbord of non-built-in solutions. This was bread-and-butter stuff in the Perl world. I was hoping the core `readline` capability would solve my issues, but alas